# Creating a new JSP page or using existing one from efficiency stand point

Tags: java, jsp

I was trying to understand the impact of creating a new jsp page. I can either use an existing Jsp by using logic but I feel that I do not need to write logic if I use a new one. Is there any negative effect in terms of resource if I create a new Jsp page?

Comment: Any effect in terms of resource is too small to matter. Write your code the best way it makes sense, so it's easy to follow and easy to maintain.

Comment: The only big impact is the converter JSP page into a servlet and the allocator the pool instances of the servlet